# almacenar y leer ficheros serializables

Tags: java

estoy intentando guardar String[] en un array y este guardarlo en un object, pero sólo me deja guardar uno al siguiente me salta un java.io.EOFException

```
    private static void AñadirCliente(String nif, String nombre, String        
       telefono, String direccion, float deuda, File archivo) {
       MyObjectOutputStream escribir;
       ObjectInputStream leer;
       String[] datos = new String[5];
       datos[0] = nif;
       datos[1] = nombre;
       datos[2] = telefono;
       datos[3] = direccion;
       datos[4] = String.valueOf(deuda);
       try {

          ArrayList<String[]> lista = new ArrayList<>();
          if (archivo.exists()) {
            escribir = new MyObjectOutputStream(new   FileOutputStream(archivo, true));
            leer = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(archivo));
            lista = (ArrayList<String[]>) leer.readObject();
            lista.add(datos);
        } else {
            escribir = new MyObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(archivo));
            lista.add(datos);
        }
        escribir.close();
```

Comment: ¿? Creas el fichero pero nunca escribes en él, si lo revisas verás que el tamaño es cero.

Comment: muchas gracias era eso el error